# iAd appear in different places

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, iad, swift2

I in first time make `iAd`. I placed `iAd` banner in the top of `UIViewController`, but when I launch app, `iAd` is in the bottom of `UIViewController`. I made constraints. Still I want to tell that sometimes `iAd` appear in the right place. I tried on simulator, iPhone 5s and iPad 3 with Cellular.

This is code which I wrote

```
    @IBOutlet weak var banner: ADBannerView!

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    NSLog("Banner View error is %@", error)
}

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    banner.hidden = false
    NSLog("Banner is loaded")
}
```

Screenshots 
[image]
[image]

I also add `iAd` to my player, and I even put `iAd` in specific `UIView` and set constraints but `iAd` all the same appear in the bottom of `UIViewController`
These screenshots show it.

Comment: Are you using auto layout and fixing the leading edge to top  of the View?

Comment: @Frankeex Yes, I am, but I tried without layout and I got the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're implementing your own `ADBannerView` then you need to remove `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` from your `viewDidLoad`.

`self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` can be used for a no hassle way of implementing iAd banners in your application. This will create an `ADBannerView` for you and show or hide the `ADBannerView` on the bottom of your view depending on whether it receives an ad or not from the iAd network.

You either implement your own `ADBannerView` or use `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true`, not both.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the following code can `self.definesPresentationContext = true`
 from `viewDidLoad` and it works for me.